# show $P_{[n]}$ to be a vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$P_{[n]}$ be the set of all polynomials of degree exactly n.

Is $P_{[n]}$ a vector space ?

What I got while doing it - when we are adding two such $p_{[n]}$  to show closed under vector addition there may be a case that coefficient of $x^n$ becomes $0$ then it will not give $p_[n]$ .Hence not closed under vector addition.

Comment: Sounds good, but it would be better to produce an explicit example.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Also think about the $0$ polynomial.

Comment: Eg-a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n and b_0+b_1x+..+b_(n-1)-a_nx^n .Then there addition is not a polynomial of degree exactly n.

Comment: Sure, but you are over complicating matters.  Just take $x^n$ and $-x^n$.  Or, more simply, just remark that (for $n≥1$ at least) $0$ does not have degree $n$. You need to note that anyway to complete your argument.

Comment: Hence we can say that it is not a vector space right.